# Bacterial endosymbiosis of bacteria

Tags: bacteriology, symbiosis

[Endosymbiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endosymbiont) was crucial to the development of complex life and it continues to happen to this day. [The origin of mitochondria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiogenesis) see bacterial guests in archaea hosts, some of which later took in cyanobacteria which became chloroplasts. Modern "eukaryotes" have varying ranges of ancestry from these two domains with [animals being about 50-50](https://academic.oup.com/gbe/article/12/4/282/5788535). More recent endosymbiosis examples include [bacterial](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3597943/) or [protist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysia_chlorotica) guests in eukaryotic hosts.

But are there any examples of a bacterial guest endosymbiosis in a *bacterial* host? [Bdellovibrio bacteriovorus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC316158/) enters other bacteria but it destroys them much like the lytic phage cycle. Bacteria inside bacteria inside [mealybug cells](https://www.cell.com/fulltext/S0092-8674%2813%2900646-6) have been found. However, this isn't an example of a bacterial symbiosis of another free-living bacterium or even of an *extra*cellular animal-associated bacterium. Are there any examples of bacterial endiosymbiosis of bacteria that aren't intimately associated with the intracellular machinery of a eukaryote?